# GIMP How do i make 2 different colors the same

Tags: gimp

i Want to remove the black parts w/o removing the the dirt/realistic parts on the armor, if i remove the black parts so that the armor looks yellow and recolor it wont be the same, it will look 'cartonish'

[image]

Comment: With that image is almost impossible without heavely painting it again.

Answer (score 1):

To keep some of the texture in the black:

- Use the fuzzy selector to select the black (I used a threshold of 16.4, selects everything without spilling)
- *Select>Grow* by two pixels
- Make sure you have an alpha channel
- *Color/Color to alpha* and remove black (000000). The black goes transparent, but not completely...
- Add a new layer below, and fill with required color

A quick result:

[image: Quick Result]

Improvement, you can use curves on the layer mask to add more contrast to the folds on the new color (make the "S" across the pike in the histogram):

An improved result:

[image: Improved Result]

You can also try to remove a very dark gray instead of black (untested)

Edit: Ooops. Didn't see you wanted the same color all over, so another try:

- Same as above, but remove a dark gray (202020) to keep a bit more of the darkness
- Add layer below armor
- Remove the selection, sample the color and bucket fill the bottom layer with it

Same color:

[image: Same Color]

Comment: Is there a reason you are not uploading the images to SE using the post editor (and rolled back my edit which did) ?

Comment: @Cai Ignorance... I noticed the change for my first two images, and I thought that it was an automatic process, so it would be redone if needed. Removed the first two images to make sure that all three images would show identically.

Comment: Ah no problem. It was not automated, only me :) In the future you can use the image upload button in the post editor and it will upload and embed the images for you.

Comment: This method will give  a single plain color on the layer bellow  - therefore completly "cartonish" - which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @jsbueno Yes, on the layer below... but overall, modulated by the not complete transparency left by color-to-alpha (see last image above)

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming you have a good understanding of gimp. I won't get into much detail.

With that image is almost impossible without heavely painting it again.

1) Mask the black part.

2) Copy it as a new layer.

3) In curves, move up the red and green channels. Play with them to achive a simmilar color. This layer will probably be usless as a final layer, because will have too little information, but can give you a glimpse.

4) Prepare an aditional layer. Use the previous layer as a basis to paint again the shadows of the zone.

5) And following that logic, use aditional layers to paint the texture. you probably can clone some of it from other parts.